# How to return Deleted User using Microsoft Graph Module in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, graph, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

I've been using this MSOL command to check if a user is in soft-delete stage but I'm just wondering how can I do the same with Graph Module?

MSOL

```
Get-MsolUser –ReturnDeletedUsers –SearchString $CSVOwner
```

Graph

```
Get-Mguser
```

I know I might need to use Get-Mguser cmdlets but not sure how can I return only the soft-deleted user. any help or suggestion would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `Get-MgDirectoryDeletedItemAsUser` but this cmdlet is available in prerelease version 2.0.0-rc1.

It requires to install `Microsoft.Graph` module with prerelease version.

```
# check version of PowerShellGet module you need at least version 2.0
# Install-Module PowerShellGet -Force -AllowClobber

# install Microsoft.Graph module and include prerelease
Install-Module Microsoft.Graph -AllowPrerelease -Force -AllowClobber

# now you should be able to call Get-MgDirectoryDeletedItemAsUser
Get-MgDirectoryDeletedItemAsUser
```

Resources:

[Get deleted user in PS](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-powershell/issues/294#issuecomment-1558173545)